# Simple login script - encrypting login doesn't work when logging in

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm trying to make a very basic login script using PHP. I am aware that the system, as of now, is very open to SQL injection and isn't secure and all that jazz. I'm more trying to get a baseline down before I jump into security.

So I have a script that adds a user to a database. This works; however, I am stuck at the actual login script. When I attempt to login I get an incorrect password read even though I know I've input the password correctly. I am using md5 encryption (again, I know it is not secure) and I figure the error must come from how I am reading back my encryption in the database? Inputting the encrypted code in the password slot from the DB returns the same error so it's something within my password logic.

**add.php** -- My registration script

```
<?php 

//Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("myDB") or die(mysql_error()); 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

if (!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pass'] | !$_POST['pass2'] ) {
    die('You did not complete all of the required fields');
}

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_POST['username'] = addslashes($_POST['username']);
}

$usercheck = $_POST['username'];
$check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users
                      WHERE username = '$usercheck'") 
or die(mysql_error());
$check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

if ($check2 != 0) {
    die('Sorry, the username '.$_POST['username'].' is already in use.');
}

if ($_POST['pass'] != $_POST['pass2']) {
    die('Your passwords did not match. ');
}

$_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_POST['pass'] = addslashes($_POST['pass']);
    $_POST['username'] = addslashes($_POST['username']);
}

$insert = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
           VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."', '".$_POST['pass']."')";
$add_member = mysql_query($insert);
?>

 <h1>Registered</h1>

 <p>Thank you, you have registered 
     - you may now <a href="login.php">login</a>.</p>

 <?php 
 }

 else 
 {  
 ?>

 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

 <table border="0">

 <tr><td>Username:</td><td>

 <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="60">

 </td></tr>

 <tr><td>Password:</td><td>

 <input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="10">

 </td></tr>

 <tr><td>Confirm Password:</td><td>

 <input type="password" name="pass2" maxlength="10">

 </td></tr>

 <tr><th colspan=2><input type="submit" name="submit" 
value="Register"></th></tr> </table>

 </form>

 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

And **login.php** -- My login script

```
<?php 

//Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password")
  or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("myDB")
  or die(mysql_error()); 

if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_your_site'])){
    $username = $_COOKIE['ID_your_site']; 
    $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_your_site'];
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
                          WHERE username = '$username'")
                            or die(mysql_error());

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check )){
        if ($pass != $info['password']){}
        else{
            header("Location: login.php");
        }
    }
 }

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if(!$_POST['username']){
        die('You did not fill in a username.');
    }
    if(!$_POST['pass']){
        die('You did not fill in a password.');
    }

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    }

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
                          WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'")
                            or die(mysql_error());

 $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);
 if ($check2 == 0){
    die('That user does not exist in our database.
      <br /><br />If you think this is wrong <a href="login.php">
      try again</a>.');
}

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check )){
    $_POST['pass'] = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
    $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);
    $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);

    if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['password']){
        die('Incorrect password, please <a href="login.php">try again</a>.');
    }

    else{ 
        $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 
        $hour = time() + 3600; 
        setcookie(ID_your_site, $_POST['username'], $hour); 
        setcookie(Key_your_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);     

        header("Location: members.php"); 
    }
}
}
else{
// if they are not logged in 
?>

 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"> 

 <table border="0"> 

 <tr><td colspan=2><h1>Login</h1></td></tr> 

 <tr><td>Username:</td><td> 

 <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="40"> 

 </td></tr> 

 <tr><td>Password:</td><td> 

 <input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="50"> 

 </td></tr> 

 <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"> 

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"> 

 </td></tr> 

 </table> 

 </form> 

 <?php 
 }
 ?>
```

**EDIT**

I've altered my **login.php** script below:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
                      WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'
                      AND password = '".$hashedPassword."'")
                        or die(mysql_error());

//Gives error if user dosen't exist
$check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);
if ($check2 == 0){
    die('That user does not exist in our database.<br /><br />If you think this is wrong <a href="login.php">try again</a>.');
}
else{ // if login is ok then we add a cookie 
    $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 
    $hour = time() + 3600; 
    setcookie(ID_your_site, $_POST['username'], $hour); 
    setcookie(Key_your_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);     

    //then redirect them to the members area 
    header("Location: members.php"); 
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Figured it out. Turns out, I had my password character limit set below the hashes conversion so it wouldn't fit the entire hashed password in the database thus making the login always invalid.

That said, I would refer to Jason's answer to anyone who is coming here looking for help.

Comment: If you wanna get into security you shoud start to call it a hash function instead of encryption (since they are fundamentally different).

Comment: Fair. I wasn't sure if what I was saying was all that accurate ha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple accounts with the same username, then you will be looping through your while loop multiple times.  Each loop you are setting the password post variable to the md5 sum of it.  First loop through it really will be the md5 of the password they typed in.  Second and subsequent times it will be taking the md5 sum of the previous md5 sum.

Rather than changing the value of the super global POST data, just make a new variable.  This way you can always get back to the actual value they submitted, prior to any manipulation (such as the md5 function).  You also do not need to keep creating the md5 sum.  Do it once and keep that variable around.

```
$hashedPassword = md5($_POST['pass']);

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check )){
    $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);

    if ($hashedPassword != $info['password']){
    die('Incorrect password, please <a href="login.php">try again</a>.');
}
```

That being said, you also do not need to compare the value in PHP.  You can just pass the MD5 value as part of the SQL Query directly.  If you dont get any rows back you know you dont have a match.

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
                      WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'
                      AND password = '".$hashedPassword."'")
                        or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm still remaining at an incorrect password error when I fix my multiple MD5 hash problem. Just to clarify, I was essentially rerunning the MD5 over my input multiple times? And by storing the initial input in `$hashedPassword` and running it that should solve it?

Comment: Figured it out. Your solution wasn't exactly my problem but was helpful none-the-less. Turns out, I had my password character limit set below the hashes conversion so it wouldn't fit the entire hashed password in the database thus making the login always invalid. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1. For encryption of communication it is HTTPS that your site should use
2. Also why are you using cookie, you should be using session instead
3. Password is stored as md5 (or sha) hash so that it is Not in the clear for people who have access to the database
4. Your looping to search for match may be a problem with large number of users, use a select statement that matches user and password.
5. Try and look for a good sample code using key words (php, session, login) [one file login](https://github.com/panique/php-login-one-file)

Comment: Thanks for you input. At the moment I am only using a user database of 5 users (friends) and I am the sole accessor of the database. I have seen the one file login; however, I prefer the method I have right now because I feel like I understand it as it's written for a large portion of it and feel that, once understood properly, I will be able to evolve into more secure and complex scripts. Thanks for your input!

Comment: ok, then please use mysqli or PDO as mysql_ is deprecated, use SESSIONS instead of cookie, and use real escape strings function on the query inputs mysqli_real_escape_string(...)